# JSON parse error when switching to Google safeframe ads

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe, phantomjs

I'm trying to switch through all the iframes in the DOM:

```
var frames = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"));    
foreach (var frame in frames)   { 
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
    //Do stuff then switch back to default content
}
```

Some Google ad safeframes throw this exception when switching:

> "JSON Parse error: Unterminated string"

I expected Selenium to read the content as HTML rather than JSON when switching to a frame.

The Google ad [safeframe](http://www.iab.com/guidelines/safeframe/) I am trying to switch to:

```
<iframe name="1-0-2;63563;<!doctype html><html><head><style><!--a:link { color: #000000 }a:visited { color: #000000 }a:hover { color: #000000 }a:active { color: #000000 }  --></style><script><!--(function(){var b=this;var f=String.prototype.trim?function(a){return a.trim()}:function(a){return a.replace(/^[\s\xa0]+|[\s\xa0]+$/g,&quot;&quot;)},m=function(a,c){return a<c?-1:a>c?1:0};var n;a:{var p=b.navigator;if(p){var q=p.userAgent;if(q){n=q;break a}}n=&quot;&quot;};var r=-1!=n.indexOf(&quot;Opera&quot;)||-1!=n.indexOf(&quot;OPR&quot;),t=-1!=n.indexOf(&quot;Trident&quot;)||-1!=n.indexOf(&quot;MSIE&quot;),u=-1!=n.indexOf(&quot;Edge&quot;),v=-1!=n.indexOf(&quot;Gecko&quot;)&amp;&amp;!(-1!=n.toLowerCase().indexOf(&quot;webkit&quot;)&amp;&amp;-1==n.indexOf(&quot;Edge&quot;))&amp;&amp;!
```

The iFrame HTML is cut short as it's over 60,000 chars as the name attribute contains the iframes DOM.

Anyone know how I can get Selenium to switch to these google ad safeframes?

Comment: Could you share the link to the webpage you are working with? Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult due to the nature of ads that cycle, however http://express.co.uk usually has a safeframe ad there on each refresh. The safeframe ads as maked with the attribute data-is-safeframe="true" in the top level. I think it worth mentioning that FireBug has no problem parsing these safeframes, unlike Selenium.

Comment: Thanks, tried to switch from frame to frame on the express.co.uk pages..no problems encountered. Just a shot in the dark - check if you are using the latest selenium and firefox versions. Any other additional information can also help to help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for testing. I'm using the latest driver (2.53) however I should have mentioned that I am using Phantomjs. I will test again with FF and report back.

Comment: Ok, thanks, what PhantomJS version are you using, btw?

Comment: You know what, I've reproduced it! Let me experiment more.

Comment: Excellent. In answer to your previous question I am using the latest version of phantomjs (2.1.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce the problem on the http://express.co.uk/ website - from time to time, there is a safeframe added to the DOM. From what I understand, the problem is that when you try to switch to a safeframe iframe (it has `data-is-safeframe` attribute set to `true`) using the frame `IWebElement` instance or it's `id` or `name`, `PhantomJS` responds with a JSON parse error. This should be reported at the [`PhantomJS` issue tracker](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues), as it is not related to a particular selenium language bindings (I've used the latest Python/Selenium - same error is thrown).

Workarounds:

- use *[frame index](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ITargetLocator_Frame_1.htm)* to switch to the frame, worked for me (the complete Python code is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/12b98722fd45c85ed1ddc1aa4c5e2a47)). For example, here is how you can switch to the very first frame in C# (zero-based index):

  ```
  driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
  ```
- switch to `Firefox` or `Chrome` (you can run them in "headless" mode also)

Comment: I don't suppose you can give me a pointer for running Firefox/Chrome as headless in the Windows environment?

Comment: @badger110 I don't have windows experience with this, but look into using virtual displays. In case of linux, I've personally successfully used `xvfb` package with firefox..